# Member value gets nulls once I enter the class in Debug mode

Tags: c#

Having a class structure like

```
public abstract class QAbstractChart { ... }
public abstract class QAbstractChart<T> : QAbstractChart where T : QAbstractBar
{
    public List<T> mxBars;

    public void doSomeWork()
    {
         ...    // YYY
    }
}

public class QPriceChart : QAbstractChart<QPriceBar> { ...  }
```

and a caller like

```
QPriceChart xPriceChart = new QPriceChart();   // fill xPriceChart
xPriceChart.doSomeWork();                      // XXX
```

I am facing the following problem. When at line `XXX`, in the Watch, I can see xPriceChart.mxBars as non-null and containing 270 elements. As soon as I step into `doSomeWork`, `this.mxBars` appears null on line `YYY` - before even touching it and I can't figure out why.

When I compare the object addresses, `&xPriceChart.mxBarList` on line `XXX` and `&this.mxBarList` on line `YYY` return addresses different by 8 bytes.

Any hint is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: Are you certain that you are not hiding the field in your derived type?  Regardless, this is far too unclear to currently answer.  Please see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @DavidL: OK, I will come up with the shortest code that can replicate this. What do you mean by hiding the field in the derived type? Its protected, but changing to public/private does not affect the problem.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Comment: why would you expect `mxBars` to be anything but null?  You haven't shown us the code where you set it to something.

Comment: @DavidL: Yes, member hiding is not present in my code.

Comment: Not enough code to give you an answer but i agree that your are probably hiding your property. Anyway since your are using abstract classes you should be supposed to know what @DavidL meant by "hiding"

Comment: @SamIam: I am reading the contents of xPriceChart from a file using a library.

Comment: @Christopher: I never came across member hiding, only method hiding (can't this of a use for member hiding - I will google some later)

Comment: @DanielBencik for all we know, there's a problem with that logic.  Why don't you include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can get a better picture.  The SC stands for "Self-Contained"

Comment: @All: Thanks to you all. The inheritance from QAbstractChart to QPriceChart is a bit longer (6 classes in between) and I noticed I am declaring mxBarList in two consecutive descedants by error - the different addresses should have made me realize sooner.

Comment: That's the hiding issue we guessed was there, not properly but kind of... glad you figured it out